# ElasticSearch Head: query

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to run an ElasticSearch query via the HEAD to  extract all brands currently mentioned in the "brand" field of the index?

How can I do this (not using curl, just via the HEAD)?

Comment: what do you mean 'via the head' ?

Comment: The HEAD plugin which provides a web interface for viewing the index and running queries. See here: http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

Answer (score 1):

You browse to head and then Any Request tab where you can enter the queries as you like.

There you enter this then:
`{
    "size" : 0,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "facets" : {
      "Brands" : { "terms" : {"field" : "brand"} }
    }
}`

Comment: Ok, so if I replace ["user", "postDate"] with [ "brand"] I get over 1.8million hits and only 10 are displayed. Is there a way to only show all the unique brand entries and have more than 10 showing?

Comment: I changed the query so that you get a facet count over the brands instead and do not fetch any documents just the facets.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far...it's really helpful. Unfortunately, that still doesnt work. It still says over 1.8million hits and only returns 10. I know that there are around 1000 different brands across these 1.8million entries and I want to know what these are.

Comment: Didn't you get a facet listing as well that groups the brands?

Comment: The number of entries that you get back by default is 10. Just add the the `size` property to your facet request and specify how many entries you want to get back. Unfortunately there's no way by now to make it infinite.

Comment: No sorry, none of this is working. Screenshots: http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/LtpN7i.png and http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/yQkZ8z.png

Comment: If you curl it then does the query work then? So you can verify that it works at least

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to use curl. Hence, hoping to get this to work via the head plugin.

Comment: If you are not running on a system that have curl installed, I recommend you try the REST console for Chrome. It is really easy to use and makes it possible to call ES with Request body.

Comment: I have tried the REST console but I am not doing something right in the body section because I only get the generic ES index summary response.  What would be a sample command for the body section? I do apologise if this is very basic but I am desperate to get a grip on this...

Comment: Ok, so I have got the queries working via the REST console but the following code (from above) doesnt work 100%. This is what it displays: "facets": {
        "Brands": {
            "_type": "terms",
            "missing": 469229,
            "total": 2300144,
            "other": 2077586,
            "terms": [{
                "term": "amp",
                "count": 33404
            }, {
                "term": "f",
                "count": 24184
            }, {
                "term": "spencer",
                "count": 23691
...